# How to set a default value of float* argument which should be a pointer to array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to set a default value for float* (C++)
as a function argument.
For example -

```
Foo(float* x = (a default value should be {0,250}))
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: It makes little sense to have a default argument for a pointer other than `nullptr`. Do you have some other code that this came from for context?

Comment: Don't use pointers to arrays. Do use Standard Library containers like `std::vector` or `std::array`. These have proper defaults. Remember when you allocate something in C++ you need to release it or you're leaking memory, and jamming in a default allocation is typically really obnoxious as it means the first bit of code to replace it needs to clean up this now garbage value.

Answer (score 6):

Since `x` is a pointer, you cannot set a default numeric value for it. You can only set a default address. To emulate giving it a default value, have a constant `float` (or in this case a `float[2]`) somewhere with that value and make `x` default to it instead.

```
const float default_x[2] = { 0.f, 250.f };

void foo(const float * x = default_x) {
    // use x
}
```

Beware that using c style arrays is error prone and not recommended in modern c++ code. Instead, prefer [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) when the size of known at compile time or [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) otherwise. For example the following code would achieve a similar result and is safer to use :

```
#include <array>

const std::array<float, 2> default_x = { 0.f, 250.f };

void foo(const std::array<float, 2> & x = default_x) {
    // use x
}
```

Comment: And if you're willing to make the leap to `std::array`, why not go the extra mile and define a struct that captures what this 2-float value actually represents, e.g. `Point`, `Vector2D`, `Range`.

Comment: Not to argue the point, but there really isn't anything "error prone" about using an array of fundamental type. The only additional piece of information you are responsible for is the size in order to protect the bounds. A competent programmer should at minimum be able to handle that. Don't confuse this to mean that arrays of fundamental type are preferred, simply that neither they, or there use, is inherently error prone. But there is much to be said for the advantages of `std::array` and `std::vector`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I disagree. Passing an an array by pointer does not enforce the size of the array as `std::array` does. Since this application expects size 2 arrays, pointers to `float` is more error prone to passing an `std::array<float, 2>`. You could accidentally pass a pointer to a single `float` or an a longer array. Though that could be overcome by taking the array by reference (where the array size *is* checked) but most uses of c arrays quickly discard the array type in favor of a pointer and size approach from which it's hard to go back to an array type.

Comment: Of course it doesn't. If you are using an array of fundamental type, the programmer is responsible for passing the size as an additional parameter. That doesn't make them bad, it just means you are missing out on the auto size and memory handling that is one of the reasons why we have C++ to begin with. Hide the details, make containers handle what the programmer otherwise would be responsible for. Your advise is sound, `std::array` and `std::vector` provide advantages to the programmer in their use, and can save the novice from himself.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing is often better done through function overloading.

```
void f(float* arg) {
    // whatever
}

void f() {
    static float default_data[] = { 0, 250 };
    f(default_data);
}
```